# How to set PYTHONPATH differently for version 2 and 3?

Tags: python

Let's assume that I set PYTHONPATH in `.bashrc` as below:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/ver2packages
```

And when I check my python path in Python 3:

```
$ python3
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/home/user', '/ver2packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

In `ver2packages`, if there are packages having the same name with packages for version 3, there might be conflicts and errors.

Is there a way to set pythonpath for each version of Python?

Comment: The best solution is probably to use [`virtenvs` link.](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: create `filename.pth`in `/usr/lib/python27/dist-packages/` and add one line which is the path to `ver2packages`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **Linux**, you can create a symbolic link to you library folder and place it in your aimed version:

```
ln -s /your/path /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

This is not about changing `PYTHONPATH` but an alternative solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can set different `sys.path` for Python 2 and Python 3 using path configuration (`.pth`) files.

For instance, to add a directory to `sys.path` for Python 2, create a `.pth` file in any of Python 2 site-packages directories (i.e. returned by [`site.getsitepackages()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/site.html#site.getsitepackages) or [`site.getusersitepackages()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/site.html#site.getusersitepackages)):

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  6 2015, 15:43:46) 
[GCC 5.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/site-python']
```

Then create a `.pth` file (as root):

```sh
echo "/ver2packages" > /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ver2packages.pth
```

See [`site`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/site.html) module documentation for more.

Comment: For Python 3.6 on CentOS 7.9, the appropriate directory for the ```pth``` file seems to be ```/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/```, i.e. ```lib64``` rather than ```lib```.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are dependent on the operating system.

For ubuntu, if you're using the standard python packages...

If you wish to do this system-wide (and you have administrative privileges), you can add additional paths to `sys.path` via `/usr/lib/pythonN.M/site.py`.

For yourself only, the system default `site.py` files already put `$HOME/.local/lib/pythonN.M/site-packages` into your `sys.path` (*iff* it exists) so you can just create the directories and put version-specific packages there.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively way is set alias in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`, e.g.(Assume `python2` is your existing python 2 command):

```
alias py2='PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages python2'
```

, which this path can get from `import site; site.getsitepackages()`

In future simply issue command `py2` instead of python2 to do the task with version 2 packages.